# Spring-batch reader for frequently modified source

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using spring batch and I want to write a job where I have a JPA reader that selects paginated sets of products from the database. Then I have a processor that will perform some operation on every single product (let's say on product `A`), but performing this operation on product `A` the item processor will also process some other products too (like product `B`, product `C`, etc.). Then the processor will come to product `B` because it's in line and is given by the reader. But it has already been processed, so it's actually a waste of time/resources to process it **again**. How should one actually tackle this - is there a modification aware item reader in spring batch? One solution would be in the item processor to check if the product has already been processed, and only if it hasn't been then process it. However checking if the product has been process is actually very resource consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches here that I'd consider:

1. **Adjust what you call an "item"** - An item is what is returned from the reader.  Depending on the design of things, you may want to build a more complex reader that can include the dependent items and therefore only loop through them once.  Obviously this is *very* dependent upon your specific use case.
2. **Use the Process Indicator pattern** - The process indicator pattern is what this is for.  As you process items, set a flag in the db indicating that they have been processed.  Your reader's query is then configured to only read those that have been processed (filtering those out that were updated via the process phase).

Comment: Thanks. The process indicator pattern looks promising but I have a question - if I read a pages of items from the db (lets say 1000 per page) then they are already read, and even if they get processed by the items processor of the first item, they will still be passed to the item processor again - leading to, again, duplicate work being done. Am I right?

Comment: You are.  Typically the way the process indicator works is you flag the elements to be processed so they are not grabbed by anyone else, then that flag is updated to processed once it has actually been processed.  In your case, if the item would be marked as in process, you wouldn't update it, knowing that it's already been read and will be processed in the current chunk.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Final question though - in terms of spring-data-batch how would it best to be implemented? I'm thinking of a `ChunkListener` that creates an empty `Map` and then the item processor fills the map with the id's of the processed items, and before processing a new product checks to see if his id is not in the map already... Is it something like that?

Comment: You're right on the `ChunkListener`, but I'd store the flag in the db so that it lives beyond the job in the case of restarts.

Comment: Wouldn't that slow the performance a lot? I'm going to have to write to the db on every product - that seems excessive to me.

Comment: I think I need to understand your use case more.  What I'm proposing is that when you're processing item B in the context of item A...check the db...if it's marked as in process, skip it knowing that it will be picked up later in the chunk.